# How to add Dockerfile to a docker registry page?

Tags: docker

I successfully built a docker image starting from a different image and using a `Dockerfile`. I then did a `docker push` into my account in the docker registry, but I can't see the `Dockerfile` that I used in the registry page.

How do I add the `Dockerfile` I used to create the image into the registry page?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You'll need to do an [automated build](http://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) of your Docker image. Basically, you'll add the Dockerfile (and any related context) to a repo (GitHub, BitBucket, or your own), and Docker will build the image anytime it gets a webhook.

From the docs:

> Automated Builds have several advantages:
>
> - Users of your Automated Build can trust that the resulting image was
>     built exactly as specified.
> - **The Dockerfile will be available to anyone with access to your
>     repository on the Docker Hub registry.**
> - Because the process is automated, Automated Builds help to make sure
>     that your repository is always up to date.